# Воспроизведение музыки в библиотеке bass.dll в delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Цель такова - нужно сделать так, чтоб после полного (до конца трека) воспроизведения музыки выполнялось какое-либо действие, например, `application.terminate`. Не могу придумать условие - подскажите?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, bass;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  stream: hstream;
  mp3: DWORD;
  IsSYNC: HSYNC;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);


begin
if not  bass_init (-1, 44100,0,handle,0) then showmessage (' ошибка инициализации ');
stream:= bass_streamcreatefile (false,pchar('1.mp3'),0,0,0,);
if stream=0 then showmessage (' фаил не загрузился');
bass_channelplay(stream,true);
//bass_streamfree (stream); // освобождение воспроизведения
//bass_free;

end;

end.
```

Я не понял покажите полным исходником !!

Comment: @Programist Syvorov, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Покажи как IsSYNC := BASS_ChannelSetSync(mp3, BASS_SYNC_END, 0, @YOUR_PROCEDURE, nil);
У меня догадки YOUR_PROCEDURE Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
и дальше begin 
application.terminate 
end;
end.

Как я не понял ? 

Или покажи полностью как я весь код, у меня он рабочий и проверен на delphi .

Comment: Зачем людей путать покажи полностью код как это делается я ведь не так долго программирую на delphi . 

Я могу свой код прокомментировать . Полностью опишу только попросите, я не понял как добавить действие после окончания трэка .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var
mp3: DWORD;
IsSYNC: HSYNC;
...............
begin
mp3 := BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, FileName, 0, 0, 0);
IsSYNC := BASS_ChannelSetSync(mp3, BASS_SYNC_END, 0, @YOUR_PROCEDURE, nil);
end;
```

где `YOUR_PROCEDURE` - название вашего процедуры, который нужно запустить по окончаний проигрывания мелодий.

---

Я бы сделал так. Сначала создаем функцию, для запуска мп3:

```
procedure BASS_PlayFile(FileName: PChar);//передаем путь к файлу
begin
  if Channel <> 0 then
  begin
    // Открываем файл...
    Channel := BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, FileName, 0, 0, 0);

    // Начинаем его воспроизведение
    BASS_ChannelPlay(Channel, False);

    // А вот здесь используем флаг BASS_SYNC_END и указываем на нашу процедуру
    // Button2click котора будет запущена по окончанию проигривания файла
    PlaySync := BASS_ChannelSetSync(Channel, BASS_SYNC_END, 0, @Button2click, nil);
  end ;
end;
```

Потом вешаем все это на нажатие кнопки:

```
procedure TForm1.btnPlayClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    BASS_PlayFile('diskoteka.mp3')
    end;

    procedure TForm1.button2click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    Showmessage('The End!-said Button2click');
    end;

    end.
```